# UDP code only receiving first response to a broadcast

Tags: objective-c, c, networking, udp

I'm attempting to communicate with multiple [SQL Server Browser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx) services using the following c + objective-c code.

```
+ (void) doBrowseForServers
{
    // http://mbielanczuk.com/2013/07/browsing-network-for-sql-server-instances-in-c/
    // used as a reference.
    SOCKET sock;
    int broadcast = 1;

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec  = 5; // 10 second timeout
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"MSSQLBrowserServiceClient failed to initialize socket.");
        return;
    }

    // Setting socket broadcast option.
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"MSSQLBrowserServiceClient failed to set broadcast option.");
        return;
    }

    // Set a timeout so that we do not wait forever.
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"MSSQLBrowserServiceClient failed to set send timeout.", errno);
        return;
    }

    // Set a timeout so that we do not wait forever.
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"MSSQLBrowserServiceClient failed to set receive timeout.", errno);
        return;
    }

    if(sendBroadcast(sock, MSSQL_BROWSER_SERVICE_PORT))
    {
        NSString * response = [self reciveBroadcastRespondFromSocket: sock
                                                           usingPort: MSSQL_BROWSER_SERVICE_PORT];

        NSDate * lastSeen = [NSDate date];

        if(0 != response.length)
        {
           // Processing code omitted to focus on send/receive
        } // End of we had responses
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"MSSQLBrowserServiceClient failed to browse for servers.");
    }
} // End of beginBrowseForServers

bool sendBroadcast(SOCKET sock, int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in bcastAddr;
    memset(&bcastAddr, 0, sizeof(bcastAddr));
    bcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
    bcastAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    char query = 0x02;
    if (sendto(sock, &query, sizeof(query), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&bcastAddr, sizeof(bcastAddr)) == -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

+ (NSString*) reciveBroadcastRespondFromSocket: (SOCKET) sock
                                     usingPort: (int) port
{
    ssize_t recvBytes = 0;
    char buf[512] = {0x00};
    memset(buf,'\0', 512);

    NSMutableData * mutableData = [NSMutableData data];

    struct sockaddr_in recvAddr;
    memset(&recvAddr, 0, sizeof(recvAddr));
    recvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    recvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    recvAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    socklen_t recvAddrLen = sizeof(recvAddr);

    while ((recvBytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&recvAddr, &recvAddrLen)) != -1)
    {
        [mutableData appendBytes: buf
                          length: recvBytes];
    }

    if(mutableData.length <= 3)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    char * bytes = (char*)[mutableData bytes];

    // Process code removed to focus on networking bits.
    // ....

    return @"";
}
```

The problem is that I seem to only handle one server response at a time. If I run this code multiple times, I can end up receiving the results from different servers each time (one server per broadcast), but my understanding is that I should be receiving udp datagrams from all servers via a single broadcast. I've tried increasing my timeout but I still only receive results from one server per broadcast.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the culprit is in `while ((recvBytes = recvfrom` loop. I think it terminates with an error.

One typical "error" for UDP broadcasts is `WSAECONNRESET`. I don't exactly know what that means, something about destination port was not reachable. Still, that's an error that routinely occurs in an UDP broadcast. Since this error is pretty much expected and it's related to one of the broadcast targets instead of your code, the solution would be to ignore this specific error and continue loop to the next `recvfrom` (you actually "do" this when you run code multiple times). Some OS allow to configure socket to ignore `WSAECONNRESET` automatically. For example, on Windows it would be `WSAIoctl(SIO_UDP_CONNRESET)`

If this doesn't help you, please provide more information about how your code runs: how many loop iterations, does it wait up to timeout, which exact error ends loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should inspect errno after recvfrom returned -1. This will indicate if no data was available and the call returned due to a timeout (EAGAIN) or if some error happened (e.g. on the second call when you expect data from another server). Most likely your recvAddr and/or recvAddrLen data was changed after the first (successful) call and becomes invalid on the second invocation. You have to (re)initialise these variables upon each call.
Note that you initialise the recvAddr with an INADDR_ANY value, which will be overwritten with the server IP address after the first call. If recvfrom would use this address as an indication that it should only receive from this IP address it would explain the behaviour that you see. However, a standard recvfrom implementation does not use this address value.